# Encontrar el primer item que NO se repite

Tags: php, array, string

Quisiera enontrar el primer item o valor que **NO** se repite en un string, Si no encuentra repetidos retorna el primer valor. Por ejemplo:

**Entrada**

```
$str = "abcdef";
```

**Salida**

a

Otro ejemplo:

**Entrada**

```
$str = "hello world hi hey";
```

**Salida**

w

En este último ejemplo, el primer valor que **NO** se repite es "w"

Por el momento tengo algo como esto:

```
$str = "abcdef";
function SearchingChallenge($str) {
$strSplit = str_split($str);
  for($i = 0; $i < count($strSplit); $i++){
    if(is_array($strSplit)){
    return $strSplit[$i];
      }
    }
  }


var_dump(SearchingChallenge($str));
```

Agradecería algo de ayuda.

Comment: Y qué falla en tu código?

Comment: @Alfabravo por el momento estoy tratando de asimilar la lógica. Mi código parece que sólo está comparando el primer ítem.

Comment: @Alfabravo creo que revisaré a detalle la función "strpos".

Comment: Es decir que no es tu código (o lo escribiste sin haberte tomado un café)? ;-)

Comment: @Alfabravo ya lo solucioné. Estoy aprendiendo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esto solucinó mi pregunta. Muchas gracias.

```
$str = "abcdef";
function SearchingChallenge($str){
  $e = null;
    for($i = 0; $i <= strlen($str); $i++)  
     if(substr_count($str, substr($str, $i, 1)) == 1){
       return substr($str, $i, 1);
     }
}
//keep this function call here  
echo SearchingChallenge($str);
```

Answer (score 0):

Usa la función array_count_values para determinar cuantas veces se repite cada caracter en una cadena, visita la pagina: [array-count-values](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.array-count-values.php) para saber mas del tema

```
$str = "hello world hi hey";

$array = str_split($str);
$valores = array_count_values($array);
$i = 0;
$letra = "";
foreach ($valores as $key => $val) { //recorre el texto caracter por caracter
    if ($val == 1 && $letra == ""){ //determina si el valor se repite solo una vez y que no haya datos en la variable letra
      $letra = $key;
      echo($letra); //muestra la letra que se repite solo una vez
    }
}
```